# An elegant way to keep integrity of RelativeLayout when animating it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, animation

Ok, so...

I know, there's been a real amount of questions about it, but it either didn't work, or was really fixed in a hard way. Oh, and that's my second day trying to do it, so please, accept my apologies about that and help me for Chet Haase's sake.

I have a button on top of a fragment, and a RecyclerView below it. When i press the button i want it to disappear and a new RelativeLayout with textfields to slide from the top. 
I don't want to make it with animateLayoutChanges="true", cause it's not exactly what i was meant to do, and i want rather learn, than do it.

I tried to do it with widget.animate().translation... and the result was that one widget was just thrown in it's place when the rest of layout stood still. That's not what i meant to do.

I tried also to make an "new TranslateAnimation" since it has this "setFillAfter/Before" attribute... but that did not help me neither.

What i tried as well was to update the layout somehow adding to id margins and stuff (don't remember anymore, and i'm in work right now trying to figure it out, sorry) as it was described in some questions.

But none of that worked. I don't include code right now, cause i already tried to do it in some dozens of different ways.

Could you please tell me  how to move a widget and make the rest of them to move with it? Is it possible?

I've already got it going once using setVisibility,animateLayoutChanges and animation combination, but that was massive and dirty as a baby duck.

Edit: oh, i almost forgot about it. Another problem is that when i animate/move a widget, only the rendering spod changes, but the real spot of it stays the same (ex. a onclicklistener)

Comment: "how to move a widget and make the rest of them to move with it" - Animate the `ViewGroup` that contains the widget.

Comment: Hmm... yeah, but look - i don't want to move some widgets together. All my fragment contains in first step is a button and a RecyclerView. I might have not understood you, but i don't see how should i do it with viewgroup.

I want to slide a prepared RelativeLayout from top and make it push down the Recyclerview.

Comment: Would Fragment Transition Animations be suitable? [Here's an Example of how it looks](https://youtu.be/XT3pq-ppCM8)

Comment: Ney, i just want to move particular widgets, not all the fragment

Answer (score 0):

Ok, me again.

I did it this way, that - let's say - i want to slide a button up and remove it.
So i animate it and all the other widgets (right, i can make a ViewGroup) up, put a listener on animation, and on "onAnimationEnd" i clear all the animations and set the visibility to GONE.
The animateLayoutChanges must be set to false

Still it's not what i wanted, so i'd be indebted to anyone who shows me another, better way.